# Issues while database connection in Next.js

Tags: mongodb, next.js, database-connection, next.js13

I am trying to connect to the data base for signup. but it is throwing the error. I have defined the mongodb path in .env file and used it in the dbConnect file for database connection.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

export async function connect() { try { mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI!); const connection = mongoose.connection;
    
connection.on('connected', () => {
        console.log('MongoDB connected successfully');
    })

    connection.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('MongoDB connection error. Please make sure MongoDB is running. ' + err);
        process.exit();
    })

} catch (error) {
    console.log('Something goes wrong!');
    console.log(error);
    
}
}
```

here is the error log:

```
MongoDB connection error. Please make sure MongoDB is running. MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
    at async invokeRequest (/Users/shahnawaz/Documents/Shahnawaz/next-app/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/server-ipc/invoke-request.js:21:12)
    at async invokeRender (/Users/shahnawaz/Documents/Shahnawaz/next-app/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:229:29)
    at async handleRequest (/Users/shahnawaz/Documents/Shahnawaz/next-app/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:422:24)
    at async requestHandler (/Users/shahnawaz/Documents/Shahnawaz/next-app/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:439:13) {
  cause: SocketError: other side closed
      at Socket.onSocketEnd (/Users/shahnawaz/Documents/Shahnawaz/next-app/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/undici/index.js:1:63301)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
      at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
    code: 'UND_ERR_SOCKET',
    socket: {
      localAddress: '127.0.0.1',
      localPort: 58557,
      remoteAddress: '127.0.0.1',
      remotePort: 58495,
      remoteFamily: 'IPv4',
      timeout: undefined,
      bytesWritten: 868,
      bytesRead: 0
    }
  }
}
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
    at async invokeRequest (/Users/shahnawaz/Documents/Shahnawaz/next-app/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/server-ipc/invoke-request.js:21:12)
    at async invokeRender (/Users/shahnawaz/Documents/Shahnawaz/next-app/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:229:29)
    at async handleRequest (/Users/shahnawaz/Documents/Shahnawaz/next-app/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:422:24)
    at async requestHandler (/Users/shahnawaz/Documents/Shahnawaz/next-app/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:439:13) {
  cause: SocketError: other side closed
      at Socket.onSocketEnd (/Users/shahnawaz/Documents/Shahnawaz/next-app/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/undici/index.js:1:63301)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
      at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
    code: 'UND_ERR_SOCKET',
    socket: {
      localAddress: '127.0.0.1',
      localPort: 58561,
      remoteAddress: '127.0.0.1',
      remotePort: 58495,
      remoteFamily: 'IPv4',
      timeout: undefined,
      bytesWritten: 647,
      bytesRead: 0
    }
  }
}
```